# How to remove tooltip when hovering an inner object?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I have an outer div with an image inside, both have tooltips. Clicking either element performs a different action:

- Clicking the outer `div`, selects the image.
- Clicking the inner `img`, opens the image.

I'd like to differentiate the actions, so when the image is hovered, the outer tooltip doesn't show up.

[image]

Here's the html:

```
<div class="outer-tip"  title="SELECT image"  data-toggle="tooltip">
  <a class="inner-tip"  title="OPEN image"    data-toggle="tooltip">
    <img src="...">
  </a>
</div>
```

1. Here's a ***FIDDLE*** with no attempts to fix this: https://jsfiddle.net/qmskzah6/
2. Here's one where I try z-index: https://jsfiddle.net/qmskzah6/1/
3. Here's where I move the image outside the div: https://jsfiddle.net/qmskzah6/2/

3 is the closest to what I want, but if you add more images it gets janky, as seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/qmskzah6/3/

I can probably mangle my way to something that works, but I'm wondering if there is a built-in or more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it seems like there is no 'built-in' option, I felt better about making a custom solution:

```
$( '[data-toggle="tooltip"] [data-toggle="tooltip"]' ).hover( 
    e => { // mouseIn
        var t = $( e.target ).parents( '[data-toggle="tooltip"]' ).siblings('.tooltip');
        if( t.is( ':visible' ) )
            t.hide(  );
    }, 
    e => { // mouseOut
        var t = $( e.target ).parents( '[data-toggle="tooltip"]' ).siblings('.tooltip');
        if( t.is( ':hidden' ) )
            t.show(  );
    }
);
```

---

I'll go through line-by-line and explain the solution:

```
$( '[data-toggle="tooltip"] [data-toggle="tooltip"]...
```

1. This selector makes sure we only target nested tooltips.

```
e => { // mouseIn
```

2. We need different functions for the mouse in and out events. There's perhaps a more efficient way to do this, but I think this promotes readability.

```
var t = $( e.target ).parents...
```

3. Initially, I just performed the show/hide on this parent element, but it had a side-effect: moving from the inner toooltiped element back to the outer one caused the outer tooltip to only flash once, then was hidden again until the next hover. I created the `t` var since it will be used more than once.

```
if( t.is( ':visible' ) )
```

4. Logging the mouseIn/Out events showed they were called 3 times per single event. I'm not sure why that happened, but adding the check to make sure it was hidden/visible - before reversing it - fixed the issue.

*Note: Zim's answer works in the sandbox, but I didn't want to mess with the tooltip init and risk breaking tooltips in other places. My app is very large.*

Answer (score 1):

Use the `container` option...

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({container:'.outer-tip'});
```

And, then add CSS to hide the outer tooltip when the inner is hovered.

```
.inner-tip:hover + .tooltip {
   display:none !important;
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/eJOvE5qRdU